# Meteor Method not defined in Template from schema

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-helper, simple-schema

I have a meteor method defined in ClassModel.js, which is located within /server. On the client js file, I set up a template event that tries to call this function, but the function keeps throwing a ReferenceError and is undefined. Any idea why?

Code:

client/client.js

```
Template.class_disc.events({
  'click .pick_class': function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var id = $(event.currentTarget).parent('div')[0].id;
    var explo = id.split("\"");
    var id = explo[0];
    Meteor.call(findClassByID, id, function(err, res) {
      console.log(res.content);

    });
});
```

/server/classModel.js

```
Meteor.methods({
  findClassByID: function(id) {
    console.log('in findclassbyid')
    return Classes.find({ _id: id }).fetch();
  }
});
```

Could the problem be that I have multiple Meteor.methods({}) declarations across different server files? Help would be much appreciated.

I mostly just need to look at the Classes collection and verify the ID's I'm pulling match some in the database, for sanity. Might there also be a way to query/publish the whole classes database to the client so I can query it within the console?

Answer (score 0):

lol wow, this turned out to be a syntax error.
When calling Meteor.methods, the method name needs to be in quotations!

Meteor.call("methodName", args, callback);